# HoverTool for multiple data series in bokeh scatter plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I have the following small example script making use of numpy and bokeh:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from bokeh.objects import HoverTool 
bp.output_file('test.html')

fig = bp.figure(tools="reset,hover")
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
s1 = fig.scatter(x=x,y=y1,color='#0000ff',size=10,legend='sine')
s1.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
s2 = fig.scatter(x=x,y=y2,color='#ff0000',size=10,legend='cosine')
s2.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
bp.show()
```

The problem is that the hover tool only works for the cosine curve but not for the sine.

I know that one option would be to plot both series togehter and change the color of the cosine data points:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bp
from bokeh.objects import HoverTool 
bp.output_file('test.html')

fig = bp.figure(tools="reset,hover")
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)

y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

x = np.array([x,x]).flatten()
y = np.array([y1,y2]).flatten()

blue = np.array('#0000ff').flatten()
red = np.array('#ff0000').flatten()
colors = np.array([blue.repeat(len(y1)),red.repeat(len(y1))]).flatten()

s1 = fig.scatter(x=x,y=y,color=colors,size=10,legend='sine & cosine')
s1.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
bp.show()
```

But then I loose the legend entry for the second color.

How do I manage to be able to hover over both data sets and see the corresponding tooltip?

Thanks!

Max

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original answer was ancient and outdated, here is how to accomplish this with any modern version of Bokeh:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

fig = figure(tools="reset", tooltips=[("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y")])
s1 = fig.scatter(x, y1, color='#0000ff', size=10, legend_label='sine')
s2 = fig.scatter(x, y2, color='#ff0000', size=10, legend_label='cosine')

show(fig)
```

Comment: I got this error: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'tooltips'. I updated my bokeh using this command: pip install --pre -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/bokeh/channel/dev/simple bokeh --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Comment: Same issue as Hamid on 0.10

Comment: The tool is on *figure*: Need to do: `fig.select(HoverTool)`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'tooltips'`

Comment: This answer is ancient, and the library has changed and improved considerably in six years since this was posted. None of the `select` business is necessary at all for basic tooltips. I have updated the answer to reflect modern usage.

Answer (score 33):

Edit: Note that the approach below is necessary only if you want *different tooltips for different glyphs*. If you want the same tooltips for all glyphs, see the answer above.

---

If you want to have multiple hover tools, you need to add multiple hover tools, each configured for a different renderer. You can add them this way:

```
p = figure()

r1 = p.circle([1,2,3], [4,5,6], color="blue")
p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[r1], tooltips=TIPS))

r2 = p.square([4,5,6], [1,2,3], color="red")
p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[r2], tooltips=TIPS))
```

Comment: This should be added to the accepted answer. It is (as of now anyway) the correct way to set a different hover renderer per plot instead of per figure.

Comment: This however causes the plot to have two different icons for "Hover". Is there a way to unify this (e.g. having a single icon to toggle both)? Alternatively, would it be possible to rename the "Hover" button to something more explicit?

Comment: This is still an open issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5497 If you have the ability, please consider helping out and contributing.