# Multiple HoverTools for different lines (bokeh)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hover, bokeh

I have more than one line on a bokeh plot, and I want the HoverTool to show the value for each line, but using the method from a previous stackoverflow answer isn't working:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549243/3087409

Here's the relevant code snippet from that answer:

```
fig = bp.figure(tools="reset,hover")
s1 = fig.scatter(x=x,y=y1,color='#0000ff',size=10,legend='sine')
s1.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
s2 = fig.scatter(x=x,y=y2,color='#ff0000',size=10,legend='cosine')
fig.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"x":"$x", "y":"$y"}
```

And here's my code:

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x = [list of datetimes]
    wind = [some list]
    coal = [some other list]
    )
)

hover = HoverTool(mode = "vline")

plot = figure(tools=[hover], toolbar_location=None,
    x_axis_type='datetime')

plot.line('x', 'wind')
plot.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"y":"@wind"}
plot.line('x', 'coal')
plot.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"y":"@coal"}
```

As far as I can tell, it's equivalent to the code in the answer I linked to, but when I hover over the figure, both hover tools boxes show the same value, that of the `wind`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add renderers for each plot. Check this. Also do not use same`y label` for both values change the names.

```
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime',plot_width=800, plot_height=300)

plot1 =plot.line(x='x',y= 'wind',source=source,color='blue')
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[plot1], tooltips=[('wind',"@wind")],mode='vline'))

plot2 = plot.line(x='x',y= 'coal',source=source,color='red')
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[plot2], tooltips=[("coal","@coal")],mode='vline'))

show(plot)
```

The output look like this.
[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It also ties in with another answer on the page I linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534995/3087409

Comment: @user3087409 Yes,The underlying concept is same, whereas the solution is specific to this problem. Also you said it didn't worked for you.  So changed code to your scenario and posted.