# Using multiple bokeh HoverTool instances together with the models API

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, hover, bokeh

I'd like to use multiple `Hovertool`s in one plot together with `Hovertool`'s `names` attribute to selectivly apply each tool. Take for instance

```
hover1 = HoverTool(tooltips=[("group", "1")], names = ['line1'])
hover2 = HoverTool(tooltips=[("group", "2")], names = ['lines2'])
```

and the two data sources:

```
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
xs=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]],
ys=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]], 
))

source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
xs=[[1, 3, 2], [6, 7, 9, 8]],
ys=[[-1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1]]
))
```

I'd though the following (using the bokeh.models API) should do what I want

```
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
l1 = MultiLine(xs='xs', ys='ys', name='lines1')
l2 = MultiLine(xs='xs', ys='ys', name='lines2')
p.add_tools(hover)
p.add_tools(hover2)
p.add_glyph(source1, l1)
p.add_glyph(source2, l2)
show(p)
```

Alas the `Hovertool`s in the resulting plot do not work (i.e. no tooltips are shown). Using the bokeh.plotting API as follows and everything works as expected:

```
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover, hover2])
p.multi_line(xs='xs', ys='ys', source=source1, name='lines1')
p.multi_line(xs='xs', ys='ys', source=source2, name='lines2')
show(p)
```

**Question**: How does one replicate the result of the bokeh.plotting API with the bokeh.models API?

Comment: You can have more than one renderer on one `Hovertool`. But you can´t use more than one `Hovertool` on the same plot, as far as I know. You can customise you hover tooltips with a callback called `CustomJSHover`. Check the documentation

Comment: @ChesuCR When using the plotting API there is a warning about duplicate tools but using multiple `HoverTool`s otherwise seems to work all right (there is even an individual icon in the toolbar for each `HoverTool` that allows enabling/disabling it individually).

Comment: See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534995/9629533) for the use of multiple hover tools as well.

Comment: Ah!! Good to know. I have tried to make that work time ago and it didn´t work, maybe I had used a different tool. Anyway check if my answer that I have written is useful for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `names` attribute of the `HoverTool` model in the [**Bokeh Documentation**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool.names):

> **names**: property type: List ( String )
>
> A list of names to query for. If set, only **renderers** that have a matching value for their name attribute will be used.

With this

```
l1 = MultiLine(xs='xs', ys='ys', name='lines1')
```

You are assigning the name to the `Multiline` object and that is a glyph, not a renderer. So try this instead

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.glyphs import MultiLine
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
        xs1=[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]],
        ys1=[[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 7]],
        xs2=[[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]],
        ys2=[[4, 5, 7], [6, 7, 2]],
    )
)

hover1 = HoverTool(tooltips=[("group", "1")], names = ['lines1'])
hover2 = HoverTool(tooltips=[("group", "2")], names = ['lines2'])

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
l1 = MultiLine(xs='xs1', ys='ys1')
l2 = MultiLine(xs='xs2', ys='ys2')
r1 = p.add_glyph(source, l1, name='lines1')  # the name is assigned to the renderer
r2 = p.add_glyph(source, l2, name='lines2')
# r1.name = 'lines1'  # or you could assign the name like this as well
# r2.name = 'lines2'

p.add_tools(hover1)
p.add_tools(hover2)

# p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover1, hover2])
# p.multi_line(xs='xs1', ys='ys1', source=source, name='lines1')
# p.multi_line(xs='xs2', ys='ys2', source=source, name='lines2')


show(p)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot not only for taking time to find a solution but also explaining the solution :)

Comment: Nice!! Mark the post as the correct answer if it works. Thank you

Comment: @ChesuCR I am getting the following error. It doesn't seem to be accepting a list. Tried with plain string but it didn't work. It's been a while since you posted this so I am assuming things have changed in Bokeh 3.2.1  Error: ValueError: failed to validate HoverTool(id='p1010', ...).name: expected either None or a value of type String, got ['line1']

Comment: Ah you are right, they should have changed that at some point. I may update the answer in the future. Thanks